# Edit / Fix MANY Column Headings in Oracle Apex Report

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

There has GOT to be a faster way of doing this.  When you create an Interactive Report, and I link it to a query, column headings all come out as Proper Case.  Which is fine, except when I have 300 items that are actually abbreviations, and so instead of KOR 42  I get Kor 42.  Or instead of RLNO FE088, I get Rlno Fe088.

I absolutely do NOT want to go in and hand edit each one, especially since they changed the shortcut key from alt-1 to ctrl+/ r to go back to rendering (and which is slow to edit).

Please, someone tell me there's a way to capitalise a large amount of them (without doing ALL of them, since there are other words that should not be capitalized).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the shortcuts? Page Designer should make this happen all in one page, albiet with a bunch of clicking.

Comment: By shortcut, I meant keyboard shortcut.  Yeah, that's the problem; the clicking.  You have to separately click from the column name (on the left) over to the heading (on the right), change the heading, then mouse over and click on the next column name (on the left) again.  I don't want to do that 300+ times, I want to mass edit the headings.

Answer (score 1):

If you're after somewhere to do this once, and have them applied each time you use that table from a wizard, then [User Interface Defaults](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeutl/managing-user-interface-defaults.html#GUID-320D73C0-F50E-4167-AA2E-89D2809AC416) can help.